# HikariCP Prepared Statement Null Pointer Exception

Tags: java, hikaricp

I am trying to implement Hikari Connection Pooling(v 2.3.5).  I have everything setup and I am able to retrieve the connection from the pool, and setup a preparedstatement object.  Whenever I try to perform any operation on the prepared statement, Hikari throws an internal NPE.

```
Data Warehouse Task Error
com.hs.task.warehouse.eci.EciConversionException: Failed while converting claims...
    at com.hs.task.warehouse.eci.Claims.convertTable(Claims.java:253)
    at com.hs.task.warehouse.DataWarehouseTask.execute(DataWarehouseTask.java:76)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.proxy.PreparedStatementJavassistProxy.setString(PreparedStatementJavassistProxy.java)
    at com.hs.task.warehouse.eci.Claims.convertTable(Claims.java:68)
    ... 3 more
```

I am using a very old JDBC driver to a proprietary DB.  I have previously used Proxool with this same driver without issue.

Configuration:

```
HikariConfig hconf = new HikariConfig();
                hconf.setDriverClassName("com.dbcswc.fs.jdbc.Driver");
                hconf.setJdbcUrl("=jdbc:fs3:MyServer:9584/MyDB;encryption=off;localport=0");
                hconf.setUsername("user");
                hconf.setPassword("pass");
                hconf.setConnectionTestQuery("select 1 as test from pu");
```

Here is where the error is happening

```
PreparedStatement psClaims = con.prepareStatement(sql);
psClaims.setString(1, ECI_DT_FMT.format(lastConvertDate));
```

psClaims is NOT NULL at this point when the setString is called.

Comment: Is ``ECI_DT_FMT.format(lastConvertDate)`` returning null?

Comment: Please open an issue on the HikariCP project page, it will be easier to track and debug there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sake of simplicity, I changed this line of code in the post:

```
PreparedStatement psClaims = con.prepareStatement(sql);
```

The prepared statement was being obtained by another class that was sending the autoGeneratedKeys parameter to the driver:

```
con.prepareStatement(sql, PreparedStatement.NO_GENERATED_KEYS)
```

After some debugging, I found out that the driver was returning a NULL preparedstatement, BUT HikariCP still returned a PreparedStatement proxy object.  HikariCP was holding the reference to the NULL preparedstatement obtained from the driver and threw a NPE whenever the preparedstatement was being acted on, such as, setString().

I am not even sure if it is legal for the driver to return NULL, I would lean to it being a bug in the driver so I am not sure if it should be addressed in HikariCP or not.  I will raise an issue there with the details and see if they would like to put a check in for that situation.

Comment: As far as we can tell that is a violation of the specification.  There isn't much point in a null check for the in the pool as the only recourse would be throwing a different kind of exception. Any defective driver can cause or throw invalid (non-SQLException) exceptions at any time and it is not the responsibility of the pool to catch or wrap them.

Comment: Just to be clear, the driver did not throw a exception.  It returned a null prepared statement.  However, the connection pool retuned a prepared statement proxy object, but was holding on to the null prepared statement that the driver returned.  This then caused the pool to throw a null pointer when the proxied prepared statement tried to invoke a method on the underlying prepared statement.  I understand if you don't want to check it, just wanted to make sure I was explaining correctly.

Comment: I'm sure other users will appreciate the clarification.  I didn't mean to imply that the driver was throwing an exception itself, but that throwing an exception (even a NullPointerException) as a result of invalid state is not in and of itself a bad thing, as it can just as surely, and sometimes more directly, lead to the diagnosis of the cause.